trouble decompiling apk
I have been trying to find the code of this game called House of the Lost for a long time. It is for a platform called the Ouya. I believe it was made using corona sdk. Also if you do manage to do it please tell me how. Here is the link to the download site https://archive.org/details/ouya_com.f5games.hotlouya_1.0.1 download the android package archive.
I tried to use corona archiver but when I did it worked but when I looked at the result it was still gibberish. am I doing something wrong or is it impossible?

The APK file can be extracted as a zip.
Using the Corona-archiver you can extract the content of the resource.car file.
Using unluac you can decompile the *.lu files.
However, at this point you will notice that all the names of local variables are gone and thus unrecoverably hard to read.

is there a way to make it easier to read and less obfuscated?

Yes, manually renaming to what it could have been, or asking the original author

the files are obfuscated - they look like usual Lua 5.1 bytecode files, without obfuscation

@ESkri You are right, I used the wrong name here. Tho, shouldn't local names be included in compiled files?

Debug info was stripped, as usual, for saving space.

Is there a way to find the names of the variables without renaming it to what it could have been or asking the original author?

Also is the resource.car file where the source code is or where is it?

Again. the names are gone, without wizardry you can not recover them. Yes code files are in the resource,car,
